# understanding some embedded erb in Rails with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is a chunk of code for a modal in bootstrap. I am trying to fully grasp what is happening and i am having trouble with `role-options-<%= user.id %>` both in the href= and div id tags. I just am not getting what is happening here. I feel like it is passing data some how. I also am not sure how to search correctly for this. So if anyone has any insight for me or places they could point to that would explain this one line.

is it linking directly to the div and passing the user.id?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Change role</a>
    <%= render user %>


<div id="role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="modal" style="display: none;">
<%= simple_form_for user, :url => user_path(user), :html => {:method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<div class="modal-header">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
  <h3>Change Role</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= f.input :role_ids, :collection => Role.all, :as => :radio_buttons, :label_method => lambda {|t| t.name.titleize}, :label => false, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', checked: user.role_ids.first %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= f.submit "Change Role", :class => "btn" %>
  <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere you see `<%= ... %>` tags in ERB markup, the Ruby code within the tags is being run and the result is printed out as text in the template (technically, the resulting value from the Ruby code has the `#to_s` method called on it, to convert it to a String).

So in this snippet:

```
<div id="role-options-<%= user.id %>"
```

the ERB template is generating a `<div>` element with an `id` attribute whose value is "role-options-", where  will be whatever the Ruby code `user.id.to_s` returns.

And this snippet is similar: its creating a link (`<a>`) element whose `href` attribute is of the form `#role-options-<user ID>`. The only difference is that it begins with `#`, which means the link will be a page anchor, i.e. it will link to a different section of the same page, namely to the previously mentioned `<div>`.

Comment: what is the href then just the link that displays in the address? thankyou for the explanation it was great. from what i gather I think my issue lies elsewhere. But that helps clarify a few things.

Comment: Yeah i just updated my answer to include the `<a href...>`. Happy to help, and I always appreciate an up-vote if you found it useful! Thanks

Comment: Yes Sir. While it did not directly solve my problem it did help a lot. I thought that line was some how passing data to the div. Its really just an anchor to the bootstrap junk.